# Magento1.9: Price changes to zero after selecting an option

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, price, custom-options

I updated my Magento version to 1.9.2.2 recently.

After updated to new version, if I select the price of the product, that cost is showing normally fine till here.

The main problem is if I select any option like color, size That product's price is showing ZERO.

Comment: Why You offer bounty if you already have an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code posted in the accepted answer cannot be found in a default Magento install.

Thus I'm pretty sure the issue can be caused by the JavaScript method called `reloadPrice`.

Interestingly, when checking the block that renders the attribute dropdown you can find this:

```
if (!$this->getSkipJsReloadPrice()) {
    $extraParams .= ' onchange="opConfig.reloadPrice()"';
}
```

I'm pretty sure you can set that parameter via layout XML by doing this:

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.options">
        <action method="setData">
            <name>skip_js_reload_price</name>
            <value>true</value>
        </action>
    </referencen>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found the solution for this issue.
First of all, we need to go to this path

```
app/design/[your package]/[yourtheme]/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml
```

Search for this script

```
price += parseFloat(config[optionId][element.getValue()]);
```

Replace with

```
price += parseFloat(config[optionId][element.getValue()].price);
```

Now it is cleared.

Comment: I couldn't find this line.

Comment: @user1240207, have you searched for    price += parseFloat(config[optionId][element.getValue()]);       ?

Comment: Yes, definitely I did search for it in 1.9.2.2

Comment: Okay, Can you share the code of your file at app/design/[your package]/[yourtheme]/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml?

Comment: Where can i find this "parseFloat(config[optionId][element.getValue()])" in magento 1.9.4 ? @TejaBhagavanKollepara

Comment: @SyedIbrahim, please check once my answer. I added the path also. Or else, Please share the code from above path

Comment: @TejaBhagavanKollepara please check this below link. This is the code which am having.

https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml