# Magento 1.9.3.1 option price not update total price

Tags: magento-1.9, price, custom-options

I have an issue on simple products with option. When selected the option the price not update.

I need help to solve it.

This is my options.phtml :

```
    <?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2016 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
/* @var $this Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options */
?>

<?php $_options = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getOptions()) ?>
<?php if (count($_options)):?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var optionFileUpload = {
        productForm : $('product_addtocart_form'),
        formAction : '',
        formElements : {},
        upload : function(element){
            this.formElements = this.productForm.select('input', 'select', 'textarea', 'button');
            this.removeRequire(element.readAttribute('id').sub('option_', ''));

            template = '<iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" style="width:0; height:0; border:0;"><\/iframe>';

            Element.insert($('option_'+element.readAttribute('id').sub('option_', '')+'_uploaded_file'), {after: template});

            this.formAction = this.productForm.action;

            var baseUrl = '<?php echo $this->getUrl('*/product/upload') ?>';
            var urlExt = 'option_id/'+element.readAttribute('id').sub('option_', '');

            this.productForm.action = parseSidUrl(baseUrl, urlExt);
            this.productForm.target = 'upload_target';
            this.productForm.submit();
            this.productForm.target = '';
            this.productForm.action = this.formAction;
        },
        removeRequire : function(skipElementId){
            for(var i=0; i<this.formElements.length; i++){
                if (this.formElements[i].readAttribute('id') != 'option_'+skipElementId+'_file' && this.formElements[i].type != 'button') {
                    this.formElements[i].disabled='disabled';
                }
            }
        },
        addRequire : function(skipElementId){
            for(var i=0; i<this.formElements.length; i++){
                if (this.formElements[i].readAttribute('name') != 'options_'+skipElementId+'_file' && this.formElements[i].type != 'button') {
                    this.formElements[i].disabled='';
                }
            }
        },
        uploadCallback : function(data){
            this.addRequire(data.optionId);
            $('upload_target').remove();

            if (data.error) {

            } else {
                $('option_'+data.optionId+'_uploaded_file').value = data.fileName;
                $('option_'+data.optionId+'_file').value = '';
                $('option_'+data.optionId+'_file').hide();
                $('option_'+data.optionId+'').hide();
                template = '<div id="option_'+data.optionId+'_file_box"><a href="#"><img src="var/options/'+data.fileName+'" alt=""><\/a><a href="#" onclick="optionFileUpload.removeFile('+data.optionId+')" title="Remove file" \/>Remove file<\/a>';

                Element.insert($('option_'+data.optionId+'_uploaded_file'), {after: template});
            }
        },
        removeFile : function(optionId)
        {
            $('option_'+optionId+'_uploaded_file').value= '';
            $('option_'+optionId+'_file').show();
            $('option_'+optionId+'').show();

            $('option_'+optionId+'_file_box').remove();
        }
    }
    var optionTextCounter = {
        count : function(field,cntfield,maxlimit){
            if (field.value.length > maxlimit){
                field.value = field.value.substring(0, maxlimit);
            } else {
                cntfield.innerHTML = maxlimit - field.value.length;
            }
        }
    }

    Product.Options = Class.create();
    Product.Options.prototype = {
        initialize : function(config) {
            this.config = config;
            this.reloadPrice();
            document.observe("dom:loaded", this.reloadPrice.bind(this));
        },
        reloadPrice : function() {
            var config = this.config;
            var skipIds = [];
            $$('body .product-custom-option').each(function(element){
                var optionId = 0;
                element.name.sub(/[0-9]+/, function(match){
                    optionId = parseInt(match[0], 10);
                });
                if (config[optionId]) {
                    var configOptions = config[optionId];
                    var curConfig = {price: 0};
                    if (element.type == 'checkbox' || element.type == 'radio') {
                        if (element.checked) {
                            if (typeof configOptions[element.getValue()] != 'undefined') {
                                curConfig = configOptions[element.getValue()];
                            }
                        }
                    } else if(element.hasClassName('datetime-picker') && !skipIds.include(optionId)) {
                        dateSelected = true;
                        $$('.product-custom-option[id^="options_' + optionId + '"]').each(function(dt){
                            if (dt.getValue() == '') {
                                dateSelected = false;
                            }
                        });
                        if (dateSelected) {
                            curConfig = configOptions;
                            skipIds[optionId] = optionId;
                        }
                    } else if(element.type == 'select-one' || element.type == 'select-multiple') {
                        if ('options' in element) {
                            $A(element.options).each(function(selectOption){
                                if ('selected' in selectOption && selectOption.selected) {
                                    if (typeof(configOptions[selectOption.value]) != 'undefined') {
                                        curConfig = configOptions[selectOption.value];
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (element.getValue().strip() != '') {
                            curConfig = configOptions;
                        }
                    }
                    if(element.type == 'select-multiple' && ('options' in element)) {
                        $A(element.options).each(function(selectOption) {
                            if (('selected' in selectOption) && typeof(configOptions[selectOption.value]) != 'undefined') {
                                if (selectOption.selected) {
                                    curConfig = configOptions[selectOption.value];
                                } else {
                                    curConfig = {price: 0};
                                }
                                optionsPrice.addCustomPrices(optionId + '-' + selectOption.value, curConfig);
                                optionsPrice.reload();
                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        optionsPrice.addCustomPrices(element.id || optionId, curConfig);
                        optionsPrice.reload();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    function validateOptionsCallback(elmId, result) {
        var container = $(elmId).up('ul.options-list');
        if (result == 'failed') {
            container.removeClassName('validation-passed');
            container.addClassName('validation-failed');
        } else {
            container.removeClassName('validation-failed');
            container.addClassName('validation-passed');
        }
    }
    var opConfig = new Product.Options(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
    //]]>
    </script>
    <dl>
    <?php foreach($_options as $_option): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getOptionHtml($_option) ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I tryed this solution: [price changes to zero after selecting an option in updated version](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90338/price-changes-to-zero-after-selecting-an-option-in-updated-version?answertab=oldest#tab-top)
but not work becouse in my options.phtml file there isn't this line:

```
price += parseFloat(config[optionId][element.getValue()]);
```

Comment: did you find solution or you looking for solution?

Comment: No, I haven't yet solution. I looking for solution.

Comment: its issue of product_options.js file not include in product view page. see my answer and add js using below code

Answer (score 0):

```
app/design/frontend/theme_package/layout/catalog.xml
```

Place this code in this file

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product_options.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>
    </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```